# Footer text disappears in Outlook/Windows email testing

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

Not sure why this is happening. The footer text completely disappears in Outlook/Windows email testing. All other email clients work and, the footer appears, as it should.
    Here is the template with the footer code. Did I miss closing a `table` or? Any suggestions? So odd-thanks for looking.

````
```

    `<table role="presentation" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
           <tr>
              <td align="center" class="darkmode-footer" bgcolor="#122147" style="padding: 50px 15px;">
                 <table role="presentation" class="w100p" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 600px; max-width: 600px;">
                    <tr>
                       <td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank"><!--[if !mso]><! -->
                            <div style="text-align: center;">


<br>
 <span style="font-size:10px;"><span style="color:#ffffff;">You are receiving this email because you are a valued friend of the .<br>
 Please note that your personal information is kept private and is never shared with other organizations.<br>
 <br>
 Want to change how you receive these emails?<br>
  You can </span></span><a href="%%profile_center_url%%" style="text-decoration: none; color:#ffffff; "><span style="color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; text-decoration: underline;">change your subscription preferences here</span></a><span style="color:#ffffff; font-size:10px;">.<br>
 <a href="%%view_email_url%%" style="color: #ffffff; font-size:10px;">View this email in a browser</a>.<br>
 <span style="color: #122147;">%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%% %%Member_Busname%% %%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%% %%Member_PostalCode%% %%Member_Country%% %%[ endif ]%%</span></span></div> </td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>

              </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
````

Answer (score 0):

If you put the code which you posted into a *snippet*  here (as I did) and in the editor click "Tidy" to properly format it, you will notice a non-fitting `</td>`in the 9th-to-last line, and also these superfluous closing tags in the last three lines:

```
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The snippet's browser emulator obviously is tolerant in fixing these errors, but I can imagine that especially mail applications like Outlook won't be that tolerant and treat this in another way.

```html
<table role="presentation" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" class="darkmode-footer" bgcolor="#122147" style="padding: 50px 15px;">
      <table role="presentation" class="w100p" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 600px; max-width: 600px;">
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><a href="" target="_blank"><!--[if !mso]><! -->
            <div style="text-align: center;">
               <br>
                 <span style="font-size:10px;"><span style="color:#ffffff;">You are receiving this email because you are a valued friend of the .<br>
     Please note that your personal information is kept private and is never shared with other organizations.<br>
     <br>
     Want to change how you receive these emails?<br>
      You can </span></span><a href="%%profile_center_url%%" style="text-decoration: none; color:#ffffff; "><span style="color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; text-decoration: underline;">change your subscription preferences here</span></a><span style="color:#ffffff; font-size:10px;">.<br>
     <a href="%%view_email_url%%" style="color: #ffffff; font-size:10px;">View this email in a browser</a>.<br>
     <span style="color: #122147;">%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%% %%Member_Busname%% %%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%% %%Member_PostalCode%% %%Member_Country%% %%[ endif ]%%</span></span>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray `<!--[if !mso]><! -->`, without a closing if (endif).

Remove that, and the text will show.